# Check the main memory usage by a linux command

Tags: linux, shell, memory

Is there any command that I could use to check the memory usage for a single linux command? For instance I have a script file (test.sh) which will read and extract word from a 100mb text file. How could I know how much memory does this command (./test.sh input_file.txt) would take?
Thanks for the advises there!!

Comment: belongs to [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `top` to see that. When you execute your script, a shell process such as `bash`, will be create to execute the script for you. So, find the shell process in `top` and you can see how many memory it uses.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `free` command to check the usage of RAM.

To check the size of the program in memory you can check the `/proc/[pid]/statm` file. For details of the format of this file read [`man proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

Fetch the PID of the script from the script using the `$$` variable (in bash).

**EDIT**

Other solutions:

`ps u $PID | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5,6` Gives you the VMZ and RSS of the process with `$PID`.

Or may want to like to see only the process memory using

`watch -n0.5 ps u $PID`

this will update the usage of the memory for your process every 0.5 secs. Adjust the value for updating as required.